# Kubernetes on Mesos Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, mesos

Hi I am setting up Kubernetes on top of Mesos by following http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/mesos.html and this is how my current test lab looks like

1. 2 Numbers of mesos master with zookeeper
2. 2 Numbers of mesos slaves with docker and flannel installed
3. Additional mesos slave running Kubernetes-mesos and kubernetes srvices
4. A server with ETCD service which supports both flannel and kubernetes

Can you please let me know if this is enough ?
Below are the two questions I have

1. Do we really need to have the kubernetes master server here to be configured as a mesos slave?
2. Do we need to install kubernetes package on mesos slaves as well ? The url talks about package installation and configuration only on the kubernetes master..With out kubernetes running on the slaves can the master create pods/services etc on the slaves through mesos scheduler?

Comment: I found answer for one of my question.Yes the Kubernetes master has to be running as mesos slave .Else it will error out saying,trying to dial http://localhost:5050 and fail..

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Mesos Masters and Zookeeper instances, to have an even number of nodes is not really a good idea, because of the quorum mechanisms involved. My suggestion would be running three nodes of both services.

I assume you want to run this locally? If so, I guess it would make sense to use a preconfigured Vagrant project such as https://github.com/tobilg/coreos-mesos-cluster This launches a three node CoreOS cluster with all the Mesos/Zookeeper services already installed, and `etcd` and `flanneld` are also already installed on CoreOS itself.

This would mean that you only would have to do the following steps once the cluster is launched:

- http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/mesos.html#deploy-kubernetes-mesos respectively https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/getting-started.html
- http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/mesos.html#start-kubernetes-mesos-services

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions Tobi . You are right, I will add additional masters and slaves .Do you know if we need to start kubernetes master service on a mesos slave itself or can we have it on a machine external to the cluster ? My other question was if we need to install kubernetes on mesos slaves or not. With out kubernetes running on the slaves can the master create pods/services etc on the slaves? And thanks for the suggestion on vagrant image..I did use it in the past :) just want to try it differently this time

Answer (score 0):

1)Kubernetes master doesnt need to be a mesos slave . 
2)You dont need kubernetes to be installed on the minions(mesos-slaves)

All you need is  below
1)Mesos setup (Mesos masters and slaves along with zookeeper ,docker running on all mesos slaves)
2)etcd cluster ,will provide overlay network(flannel) and also will do the service discovery of kubernetes setup
3)kubernetes master ..

Below blogs helped a lot in setting it up
http://manfrix.blogspot.in/2015/11/mesoskubernetes-how-to-install-and-run.html
https://github.com/ruo91/docker-kubernetes-mesos